# Drupal Hooks (hook_form_alter)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, hook, fbconnect

I’ve a question about Hooks. Being kind of new to Drupal I haven’t had much experience with hooks but a friend of mine suggested to get familiar with it and learn it to solve one of my problems on my site.

The thing is, that I have a module **fbconnect** which I use for users to connect via Facebook and use their profile picture at Facebook, on my site.

Everything is working, I’ve two checkboxes which and the connection and profile images works quite well but the problem is that above the two checkboxes I want a descriptive text to appear.
The only way I so far have to put in this text is to create a “description” field to the first checkbox. Unfortunately, it chooses to display this text beneath the checkbox so now it look kind of strange with a checkbox, a 3-4 lines descriptive text to the entire Facebook function, and then another checkbox.

If **hooks** are the right way to go to solve this problem, how do I actually do it and where do I actually insert the hook? I can imagine that it is the **hook_form_alter** function I need to have and in my fbconnect module the function **fbconnect_form_alter** exists but where I go from here I really have no idea.

I’ve tried to read up and see some instruction videos about hooks but I’m still puzzled about this apparently very nice feature in Drupal.
I'm using Drupal 6 for this site.

Any help or advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might also need to look at the **Theme** system in Drupal. In particular, take a look at [theme_checkbox](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_checkbox/6). From glancing at the code, there seems to be a label that is rendered after the actual checkbox. In your custom theme function or theme file you can try changing the order of the two.

Answer (score 0):

In drupal, a "hook" is the way to interact with some piece of code.

In you have a hook_bar() hook, and is your module named 'foo' implements foo_bar(), then this function is executed.

In your case, you'll need to create a module, and impletements hook_form_alter()

You can find a tutorial [there](http://www.chromaticsites.com/blog/drupal-tutorial-form-overrides-and-element-specific-validations/) that show you how to add a checkbox. If you need to add some text, you can use the same method, except instead of adding a checkbox, of course, you just add a [textfield](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#textfield)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awesome beginner's video about adding custom hooks with the example of hook_form_alter from Drupalcon Chicago 2011 which is perfect for this situation and will hopefully help you in this. As a newbie to Drupal it surely helped me and I would highly recommend watching other videos. Thanks to the drupal community for posting these.

http://chicago2011.drupal.org/sessions/introduction-module-development